# Shearpoint: Can I Still Fight the Dragon Priest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I already defeated the dragon at Shearpoint, and I collected the bounty. But I didn't see a Dragon  Priest, so can I not complete the Dragon Masks? Or does the Dragon Priest just show up on it's own?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you walk towards the sarcophagus that he's hiding in. It's possible to learn the Word and fight the dragon without ever being near the sarcophagus.

To make him pop out, just make sure to revisit Shearpoint and walk right next to the sarcophagus.

Comment: You'll probably want to kill the dragon first.

Comment: I killed the dragon previously, so that's not a problem. Thank you for the help!